# Loop Printing (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm doing a coding challenge where I'm required to write a program that turns written numbers (e.g. "one") into integers. It seems to be working fairly well, but it's not printing the last value of the line. Does anyone know *why* this happens?

code:

```
File.open("-snip-").each_line do |line| #-snip- is just my omitted filepath
    words = line.split(";")
    words.each { |w| print 1 if w == "one"
        print 2 if w == "two"
        print 3 if w == "three"
        print 4 if w == "four"
        print 5 if w == "five"
        print 6 if w == "six"
        print 7 if w == "seven"
        print 8 if w == "eight"
        print 9 if w == "nine"
        print 0 if w == "zero" }
    print "\n"
end
```

sample input:

> three;zero;nine;zero;six;eight;eight;five;seven;eight;seven;four;three;six;seven;seven

my output:

> 309068857874367

output I need:

> 3090688578743677

Comment: [Can't reproduce the issue](http://codepad.org/PNN3bE1S)

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. It works for me.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in your actual code/file, and fixed it here. Why not add an `else` at the end to handle unexpected values?

Comment: Just a general debugging tip, if there's something unexpected in your code, try to figure out what's wrong by using a bit of debugging. In this case, I'd recommend adding a ``p w`` inside your ``each`` statement so that you can see exactly what it's looking at each time and you'd probably be able to spot the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that there's a new line character at the end of your sample input. In that case, your input should look like this:

```
three;zero;nine;zero;six;eight;eight;five;seven;eight;seven;four;three;six;seven;seven\n
```

When you call split on the line it'll return an array. The last element of that array will be `"seven\n"`. You can remove the trailing newline by calling `chomp` on the line because splitting it.

It would be

```
words = line.chomp.split(";")
```

instead of

```
words = line.split(";")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this.

```
indexes = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

File.open("-snip-").each_line do |line| #-snip- is just my omitted filepath
  output = ""
  line.chomp.split(";").each do |w|
    output += indexes.index(w).to_s
  end
  print "#{output}\n"
end
```